# jQuery - Change image src on click

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to change the src of an image on click of two different elements to change from one image, to an active image.

For example, if either .vehicle-desc-wrap or .vehicle-pic-wrap was clicked I want to be able to change the image url within this div from `images/saloon-outline.png` to `images/saloon-outline-active.png`, and the same with all the other car images.

So for example, if I click the saloon image the url changes to saloon-outline-active.png, but if I then click the Executive Saloon image, it changes the src of the executive image to `execsaloon-outline-active.png`, and every other image back to it's normal state (without -active). Here is the HTML:-

```
<div id="div-vehicle-wrap">

    <div id="div-Car" class="vehicle-item ui-corner-all req-wrapper">

    <div class="vehicle-pic-wrap ui-corner-left req-display success">

    <img class="vehicle-pic-ie6-png" height="100" width="120" alt="Standard Saloon" src="images/saloon-outline.png">

    </div>

    <div class="vehicle-desc-wrap req-display success">

    <div class="vehicle-radio-wrap">

    <div class="vehicle-accept-wrap">

</div>

<div id="div-Exec" class="vehicle-item ui-corner-all req-wrapper">

    <div class="vehicle-pic-wrap ui-corner-left req-display success">

    <img class="vehicle-pic-ie6-png" height="100" width="120" alt="Executive Saloon" src="images/execsaloon-outline.png">

    </div>

    <div class="vehicle-desc-wrap req-display success">

    <div class="vehicle-radio-wrap">

    <div class="vehicle-accept-wrap"></div>

</div>
```

So far I have the following:-

```
        $('img').click(function(){
            var src = this.src;
            this.src = src.indexOf('-active') == -1 ? src.replace('.png','-active.png') : src.replace('-active.png','.png');
        });
```

This doesn't change the none active images back to the original src and only changes the image on click of the actual image instead of the two wrapper classes; `.vehicle-desc-wrap or .vehicle-pic-wrap`

If anybody could help me with this, that would be much appreciated.

Here is a link to the web site: [LINK](http://www.marandy.com/onlinebooking_htp/login-guest.php)

Comment: you coded just the click event!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function(){
    var regexactive = /-active\..*$/;

    var ct = $('#div-vehicle-wrap');
    var imgs = $('.vehicle-pic-wrap img', ct);

    function deactiveImage(imgs){
        imgs.each(function(){
            var img = $(this);
            var src = img.attr('src');
            if( regexactive.test(src) ){
                img.attr('src', src.replace('-active.', '.'))
            }
        });
    }

    function activateImage(imgs){
        imgs.each(function(){
            var img = $(this);
            var src = img.attr('src');
            if( !regexactive.test(src) ){
                img.attr('src', src.replace('.png', '-active.png'))
            }
        });
    }

    ct.on('click', '.vehicle-desc-wrap', function(){
        var item = $(this).closest('.vehicle-item');
        deactiveImage($('.vehicle-pic-wrap img', item));
    });

    ct.on('click', '.vehicle-pic-wrap', function(){
        var item = $(this).closest('.vehicle-item');

        var img = $('.vehicle-pic-wrap img', item);
        deactiveImage(imgs.not(img))
        activateImage(img);
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/R9VYh/4/)

Comment: I've just tried this, it doesn't seem to be working, on click of any image it works the first time, but on click of another image it is chaning the src to; `images/mpv-outline-active-active.png`, and then `active-active-active` when you click the next image

Comment: Here is a link to the web page; http://www.marandy.com/onlinebooking_htp/login-guest.php

Comment: in which file do you have the script

Comment: @nsilva it was a minor bug in the regex, answer updated, check the demo

Comment: I have added the code to the same link as above, the code is in general-booking.js. What I am wanting to happen is that if you click on Standard Saloon, it changes the car image to active, but if I then click another car, say 8 Seater MPV, it changes this image to -active and removes the -active from the previously clicked image.

Comment: Thanks Arun, I've uploaded this again, the only problem is that there should only ever be one active (green) car at any time. At the moment I can make all cars active. If I click a different car, it should make the previous active car back to it's original img src